# iOS - How can I determine that the current device has the informed phone number?

Tags: ios

OK, apple won't allow me to programmatically retrieve the current phone number (with or without user consent).

Is there another way to get this positive confirmation?

Let's say that,given that the user allowed push notifications, can I send a push to a given phone number (instead of device id)? The app would capture the push and validate automatically, making it an invisible push?

Perhaps is there a way to send a SMS with a code so large that would be unfeasible to be voiced-over or copy-paste-and-send-to-someone-else-and-copy-paste-again-to-enter-value BUT that my app could pickup and the keyboard suggest as input?

Comment: From your app, ask for the user number, save it in the keychain, access when needed. Register for push notification then can send via the provided token for device.

Comment: thanks for the input but I believe you got my question wrong... the issue here is how can I verify that the number inputed belongs to the device it was inputed into?

Comment: With auto validation from OTP.

Comment: Your app cannot verify that a particular phone number is on this specific device.  Via SMS you can only verify that the user has access to the text messages sent to that specific number.